# The curren time is negative after -4 offset

Tags: java

I am new to java, I am trying to write this program as a practice. The program take the current time zone offset and display the current time. But some how my time is coming out to negative. I think there is a logic error in here but I can't find it.

```
Enter the time zone offset to GMT: -4
The current time: -2:48:26
```

I am using New York (GMT -4 hours)

```
// A program that display the current time, with the user input a offset

import java.util.Scanner;

class CurrentTime {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Create a Scanner object
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        long totalMillSeconds = System.currentTimeMillis();

        long totalSeconds = totalMillSeconds / 1000;
        long currentSecond = (int)totalSeconds % 60;

        long totalMinutes = totalSeconds / 60;
        long currentMinute = totalMinutes % 60;

        long totalHours = totalMinutes / 60;
        long currentHour = totalHours % 24;

        // Prompt user to ask what is the time zone offset
        System.out.print("Enter the time zone offset to GMT: ");
        long offset = input.nextLong();

        // Adjust the offset to the current hour
        currentHour = currentHour + offset;
        System.out.print("The current time: " + currentHour + ":" 
                + currentMinute + ":" + currentSecond);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I think there is a logic error in here but I can't find it.

I think the logic error is that when you add a negative offset to the "hours", you could end up with an hour in the previous day.  (And there is a related problem.  If the offset is large enough, you could end up with an hour in the *next* day; i.e. an "hour" value that is greater than 24 ... by your method.)

The simple fix is this:

```
currentHour = (currentHour + offset + 24) % 24;    // updated ...
```

If you don't know what the '%' (remainder) operator does, read [this](http://www.cafeaulait.org/course/week2/15.html).

What that page doesn't mention (and what I forgot) is that the sign of the remainder ... if it is non-zero ...  is the same as the sign of the dividend.  (See [JLS 15.17.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17.3)).  So we need to add `24` before taking the remainder to ensure a positive remainder.

Answer (score 2):

your problem is in the line almost at the end

```
currentHour = currentHour + offset;
```

think of this: if current hour is 1 and time offset is -4, what do you get?

you could do this:

```
currentHour = (currentHour + offset + 24) % 24;
```